# DateTime parsing not working when specified the format

Tags: c#

DateTime parsing not working when specified the format

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
    DateTime ValidUptoFO;
    string date = "10/25/2018 10:38:26 AM";
    var op = DateTime.ParseExact(date,@"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",null);
    Console.WriteLine(op);
}
```

This errors out `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`

I am trying to parse `10/25/2018 10:38:26 AM` to `DateTime`

Comment: @John you are also wrong regarding escaping. Run the following sample: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");            
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
            string date2 = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh\:mm\:ss tt");
            if (date != date2)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

Comment: `/` and `:` are time separators if they are not escaped. If they are escaped they become slash and colon.

Comment: @Access Fair enough, I'll delete my comment. Thank you for teaching me something! Using the invariant culture, of course, doesn't suffer from this issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` it will work:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        string dateText = "10/25/2018 10:38:26 AM";
        var op = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, DATE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(op.ToString(DATE_FORMAT,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The date format is `MM/dd/yyyy`, hence use proper format:

```
var op = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also no need to escape slash because it doesn't exist as escape sequence unlike backslashes.

Comment: `no need to escape slash` this actually not the case with datetime, take a look at explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

While Invariant culture solves the OP it's good to understand what is wrong with specified DateTime format.

In case you have code which save datetime with specified format and code which reads the same date with specified format. The problem is that `/` and `:` are interpreted differently in different Cultures as well as `tt`. `/` and `:` are date time separators if they are not escaped.

Let's look at the following code, which demonstrates the problem with dateformat (it will crash with invalid date format):

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
    var format = @"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,format,null);
```

Let's explain why it crashes. Let's switch to the interesting Culture, which demonstrates all the problems with dateformat in the question:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
```

The issue is that in Finland locale you will have the following result:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

> 25.10.2018 05.33.42 ip.

If you escape date separator you will get:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

> 25/10/2018 05.36.40 ip.

If you escape time separator:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy hh\:mm\:ss tt"));
```

> 25/10/2018 05:38:20 ip.

And to solve `ip.` problem specify HH format:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss"))
```

> 25/10/2018 17:45:03

And the working code will be:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi");
    var format = @"dd\/MM\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss";
    var dateString = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, null);
```

Comment: "The working code" still won't work because OP's date is MM/dd/yyyy format, not dd/MM/yyyy format.

Comment: @John Working code will work. Run it and see that it works. The idea of this answer was to explain pitfalls of the format  in the question (why it's bad to use it). It is in addition to other answers not in contrary to the other answers.