# XML Date being read with 00 for month value

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I'm reading an XML file in a C# app. The XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configs>
    <dates>
        <dateOfLastBackup value="04-09-2021"/>
        <dateOfLastManualBackup value ="05-11-2021"/>
        <dateOfLastDataWipe value="05-11-2021"/>
    </dates>
    <backupLocations>
        <backup location="No backup created yet"/>
    </backupLocations>
</configs>
```

I made the file. The dates are supposed to be in format dd-mm-yyyy.

However, I assume I'm doing something wrong and this isn't a proper way to read XML dates, because when I read them in my app, they display with the mm value as 00, for example 04-00-2021.

Method to read the XML and put the value of a date in a textbox

```
public void ShowDateOfLatestDataAction(TextBox pTextBox, int childNodeIndex)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load("./DatesAndLocations.xml");
            string date = "";
            foreach (XmlElement elem in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (elem.Name == "dates")
                {
                    var latestDate = elem.ChildNodes[childNodeIndex];
                    date = DateTime.Parse(latestDate.Attributes[0].Value).ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
 
                }
            }
            pTextBox.Text = date;
        }
```

Likewise, I need to be able to overwrite these dates from the app to the file.
Which I'm currently doing via

```
public void UpdateDateOfLatestDataAction(int childNodeIndex)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load("./DatesAndLocations.xml");

            foreach (XmlElement elem in doc.DocumentElement)
            {
                if (elem.Name == "dates")
                {
                    var elementToUpdate = elem.ChildNodes[childNodeIndex];
                    elementToUpdate.Attributes[0].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
                }
            }

            doc.Save("./DatesAndLocations.xml");

        }
```

There's most definitely another way to write dates in XML and read them but I just don't know how. I read about XmlConvert but it seems the datetime parse methods are deprecated and I don't quite understand how to use them.

Comment: Use `MM`, represent month, `mm` is for minutes. [DateTime Format in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: Also, parse in the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture)  See e.g. [DateTime parsing not working when specified the format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52981785/3744182).

Comment: If the value is already in the correct format in the XML, `date = latestDate.Attributes[0].Value` is sufficient. You do not need to parse and then ToString again.

Comment: `dd-MM-yyyy` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/VW5F6Q.  Closing as a duplicate of [DateTime ToString issue with formatting months with "mm" specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14206359/3744182).